# How do i display the objects related to a foreign key in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

my models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)


class Products(models.Model):
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="display")
engine = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
cyl = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
bore = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.engine) + "  (ref:" + str(self.ref) + ")"
```

my views.py:

```
def Companies(request):
    context = {
        'categories': Company.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'product_list.html', context)
```

HTML :

```
                {% for category in categories %}
                <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
                {% for item in category.item_set.all %}
                    {{ item_engine }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

> how do i display every objects of Products(engine,cyl,bore) following its name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get related field using **ForeignKey** try with [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)  method like this

add this in your **views.py** file

```
def Companies(request):
    context = {
        'categories': Products.objects.prefetch_related('company')
    }
    return render(request, 'product_list.html', context)
```

this will return object when you try to access your **Company** object in template like this `{{ category.company }}` it will give you output like this `Company object (1)` and you can access all attributes from your **Company** model.

add this in your template

```
{% for category in categories %}
  <h2>{{ category.company.name }}</h2>
  <p>{{ category.engine }}</p>
  <p>{{ category.cyl }}</p>
  <p>{{ category.bore }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

if you delete any **Company** it will be not displayed on template.

Comment: Sorry to disturb but this is displaying the company names . how do i get its data (engine , cyl , bore)

Comment: Hello @BilalManzoor check I have improved my answer.

Comment: AttributeError at /product_list.html
Cannot find 'company' on Company object, 'company' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()    idk what am i doing wrong here.. am i importing the right model in view ?

Comment: Hello @BilalManzoor My Bad!, Sorry check I've edited answer

Comment: Hello @BilalManzoor I've replaced `Company.objects.prefetch_related('company')` to `Products.objects.prefetch_related('company')` let me know if there is an error.

Comment: Hello @BilalManzoor did my answer solved your problem ?

Comment: now its back to the start xd.. there is a different header for every category ..  what i want is the that the products having the same company to be listed under 1 company header :( i am so glad you are able to help me this far ty.

Comment: You can achieve this by adding detail view to each company for example a company can  have many products so if user click on certain company than it will show all products that are related to that particular company.

Comment: Hello @BilalManzoor You can ask another question for this problem or can research about list view and detail view if I've helped you to solve your problem please accept my answer.